# How to copy the corresponding data of the duplicate cells with each other in google sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

Column a has duplicate data with the corresponding state in column B and I want to duplicate the state of Column B for other duplicates.
for example column A has data as "2307PT715" and column B as: "Processing". I need to duplicate this status: "Processing" for all duplicate data with "2307PT715".
Same as above: 2407PT681 will also have "done" status.

Thank you everyone for your help.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2307PT344 | Blank |
| 2307PT344 |  |
| 2307PT850 |  |
| 2307PT715 | Processing |
| 2307PT715 |  |
| 2407PT681 | Done |
| 2407PT681 |  |
| 2307PT733 |  |
| 2307PT733 |  |
| 2307PT850 |  |
| 2307PT715 |  |
| 2307PT850 |  |
| 2307PT866 |  |
| 2307PT866 |  |
| 2307PT866 |  |
| 2307PT344 |  |

Here's the result that I want.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2307PT344 | Blank |
| 2307PT344 | Blank |
| 2307PT850 |  |
| 2307PT715 | Processing |
| 2307PT715 | Processing |
| 2407PT681 | Done |
| 2407PT681 | Done |
| 2307PT733 |  |
| 2307PT733 |  |
| 2307PT850 |  |
| 2307PT715 | Processing |
| 2307PT850 |  |
| 2307PT866 |  |
| 2307PT866 |  |
| 2307PT866 |  |
| 2307PT344 | Blank |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following sample script of Google Apps Script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set the sheet name and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  // Retrieve values from the sheet in Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();

  // Create an object for searching the values of column "B" using the values of column "A".
  // Here, an object like {"2307PT344": "Blank", "2307PT715": "Processing",,,} is created.
  const obj = values.reduce((o, [a, b]) => {
    if (b.toString()) o[a] = b;
    return o;
  }, {});
  
  // Creating the destination values using the object.
  // Here, 2-dimentional array like [["Blank"],["Blank"],,,] is created.
  const dstValues = values.map(([a]) => [obj[a] || null]);
  
  // Put the destination values in column "B".
  range.offset(0, 1, dstValues.length, 1).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided sample table, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- When your actual Spreadsheet has the 1st header row, please modify `"A1:B"` to `"A2:B"`.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

### Added:

From your reply,

> Your help is very helpful and I have applied very well. however i tried applying it to the expansion, when using data in column B and status in column F or any other column the file doesn't work properly. Can you help me adjust it? Your help is very helpful and I have applied very well. however i tried applying it to the expansion, when using data in column B and status in column F or any other column the file doesn't work properly. Can you help me adjust it?

I thought that from the tables of your question, the tables have 2 columns "A" and "B". But, it seems that those columns were "B" and "F". And also, I couldn't correctly imagine your current script from your reply. So, for this situation, I updated the above script. Please confirm it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  // Retrieve values from the sheet in Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("B1:F" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();

  // Create an object for searching the values of column "F" using the values of column "B".
  // Here, an object like {"2307PT344": "Blank", "2307PT715": "Processing",,,} is created.
  const obj = values.reduce((o, [b, , , , f]) => {
    if (f.toString()) o[b] = f;
    return o;
  }, {});

  // Creating the destination values using the object.
  // Here, 2-dimentional array like [["Blank"],["Blank"],,,] is created.
  const dstValues = values.map(([b]) => [obj[b] || null]);

  // Put the destination values in column "F".
  range.offset(0, 4, dstValues.length, 1).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

Comment: The script works very well . Without you I don’t know how I would manage it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Myra Thank you for replying. About `Without you I don’t know how I would manage it.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. In my proposed script, when I saw your expected result, I noticed that the values of column "A" is not continuously existing like `2307PT344`.

Comment: @Myra So, first, I created an object for searching the values of column "B" corresponding to column "A". And, as the next step, the destination values are created by searching the values of column "A" from the object. And, the destination values are put in column "B". And, I updated my answer by adding the explanation. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Your help is very helpful and I have applied very well. however i tried applying it to the expansion, when using data in column B and status in column F or any other column the file doesn't work properly. Can you help me adjust it?
Your help is very helpful and I have applied very well. however i tried applying it to the expansion, when using data in column B and status in column F or any other column the file doesn't work properly. Can you help me adjust it?

Comment: @Myra Thank you for replying. About the new issue of your reply, your question shows 2 columns "A" and "B". But, in your reply, you say `when using data in column B and status in column F or any other column the file doesn't work properly`, unfortunately, I couldn't notice that your showing table has columns "B" and "F". I deeply apologize for this. So, I updated my answer for columns "B" and "F". Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize again.

Comment: @Myra By the way, can I ask you about the detail of `dynamic` of `with Tanaike, his script is not dynamic for other columns except column A and B data`?

Comment: don't mind it, because at first I didn't know how to tag your name. Haha...
I applied the change and it works great. I really appreciate your enthusiasm. Wishing you a day filled with joy and happiness.

Comment: @Myra About `I applied the change and it works great.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, i found the accept button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm refreshing some very rusty skills inherited from Java - some may find it interesting/amusing to compare my rather amateurish attempt with that of @Tanaike :-)

```
function autoSort(){

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var workSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet6");

  var range1=workSheet.getDataRange();

  var workArray=range1.getValues();

  for(var i=2;i<workArray.length;i++){

    if(workArray[i][0]===workArray[i-1][0] && workArray[i][1]==="") {
      workArray[i][1]=workArray[i-1][1];
    }
  }

  range1.setValues(workArray);

}
```

[image]

I have added a test case for more than two dups.

**EDIT**

Here is the modification suggested by @Tanaike so that it checks all rows for a match not just the previous row:

```
function filler(){

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var workSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet6");

  var range1=workSheet.getDataRange();

  var workArray=range1.getValues();

  for(var i=1;i<workArray.length;i++){

    var v = workArray.find(([a, b]) => a == workArray[i][0] && b.toString()); if (v) workArray[i][1] = v[1];
  }

  range1.setValues(workArray);

}
```

But still assumes data are in columns A and B.

Comment: your script works fine, but i tried to apply it to my extended data however there are some problems. some of them not working. Can you help me check it again?

Comment: I think that in your showing script when the values of column "A" are continuously existing, the script can be used. But, in the OP's sample tables, for example, the value of `2307PT344` is existing by spreading the same values. So, for example, how about modifying `if(workArray[i][0]===workArray[i-1][0] && workArray[i][1]==="") { workArray[i][1]=workArray[i-1][1]; }` to `var v = workArray.find(([a, b]) => a == workArray[i][0] && b.toString()); if (v) workArray[i][1] = v[1];`? If I misunderstood your script and OP's goal, I apologize.

Comment: @tanaike, This is the result that I have tried to apply to extended data. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSLLj.png

Comment: @tanaike and Myra many thanks for your feedback. I'm away from my computer this morning but this makes a lot of sense and is also helping me to get to grips with Javascript idiom. I will test it later today.

Comment: @Tanaike I have tried out your suggestion and of course it works perfectly. I only had to change the start of my loop to start checking at the row immediately below the header row so it became  

for(var i=1;i<workArray.length;i++) 

Many thanks.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe Thank you for your response!